# Correct loop in R to sum values from another data frame corresponding to two variables

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, sum

Good evening,

I am trying to construct the correct loop (be it `for`, `while` or `if`) that will sum the values in one column given a specific date and variable and deposit that into a specific position in the data frame.  All of my attempts at the loop have been horribly erroneous and I am clearly not getting the correct starting point!

In the below `Sample.Frame` I would like to populate the first row of the column `LON.NEW6` with the sum of the `No.of.Rooms` from the `Sample.Bookings` frame that have the `Stay.Date` that matches the `Start.Date` and `Legacy.Hotel.Code` that matches the column header.  This needs to be repeated throughout the frame.

The partially populated `Sample.Frame` data frame:

```
> Sample.Frame
                              Start.Date LON.NEW6 LON.CAP LON.CEN2 LON.MYH1 LON.SOS LON.MOW LON.HOLW LON.94V LON.FOU6 LON.949
E0-001-085571068-9            30/09/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086838711-7            07/11/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085536178-4@2015102019 20/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085466318-0            01/07/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085591039-5            30/01/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-087500856-4            29/04/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-079398784-2@2015092909 29/09/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086021337-5            14/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086639435-3            20/12/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-087220018-9            27/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
```

The `Sample.Bookings` data frame:

```
> Sample.Bookings
          City Booking.ID Legacy.Hotel.Code Star.Rating.ID  Stay.Date No.of.Rooms
1146767 London   17480238          LON NEW6              2 30/09/2015           3
220037  London   18381583          LON CEN2              3 29/09/2015           1
668476  London   15184820          LON NEW6              2 07/11/2015           1
1073551 London   16414241          LON CEN2              3 01/07/2016           1
138695  London     554331           LON CAP              5 29/04/2016           1
301805  London   17134981          LON NEW6              2 30/09/2015           1
181300  London     193930          LON CEN2              3 01/07/2016           1
1204682 London   15154547           LON CAP              5 23/07/2015           1
1549067 London   14436933          LON NEW6              2 20/10/2015           1
832903  London   13796464          LON NEW6              2 20/10/2015           1
301778  London   16304861          LON NEW6              2 22/11/2015           1
399343  London   16855128          LON NEW6              2 07/11/2015           1
399337  London   14855974          LON NEW6              2 03/04/2015           1
1472157 London   18320357          LON NEW6              2 17/01/2016           1
1184525 London   18360304          LON CEN2              3 05/02/2016           1
1342678 London   17623052           LON CAP              5 01/02/2016           1
420443  London   18381583          LON CEN2              3 20/02/2016           1
1435511 London   15230186          LON NEW6              2 22/08/2015           3
1201521 London   16319154          LON NEW6              2 05/09/2015           1
1233528 London   15460211          LON NEW6              2 28/07/2015           1
```

What I should then end up with is something beginning to look like so:

```
    > Sample.Frame
                              Start.Date LON.NEW6 LON.CAP LON.CEN2 LON.MYH1 LON.SOS LON.MOW LON.HOLW LON.94V LON.FOU6 LON.949
E0-001-085571068-9            30/09/2015       3       NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086838711-7            07/11/2015       1       NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085536178-4@2015102019 20/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085466318-0            01/07/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-085591039-5            30/01/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-087500856-4            29/04/2016       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-079398784-2@2015092909 29/09/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086021337-5            14/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-086639435-3            20/12/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
E0-001-087220018-9            27/10/2015       NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA      NA       NA      NA
```

Where all elements are populated with the sums OR remain as NAs if there are no bookings that correspond with that date and variable.  This is a small sample but the set I am working with may have thousands of rows and hundreds of columns.

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: The solutions provided were helpful, however I would still like to understand how to process this through a loop(s) due to eventual expansion of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with the `dcast` function from `reshape2` and `merge`  From the `Sample.Frame` data.frame all you really need to keep is the `Start.Date` and potentially the row names (if those have relevant information)

```
library(reshape2)

# all you need is the Start.Date and the row names
Sample.Frame <- data.frame(Start.Date = c("30/09/2015", "07/11/2015", "27/10/2015"))
Sample.Frame$row.names <- row.names(Sample.Frame)


# test data.frame
Sample.Bookings <- data.frame(Legacy.Hotel.Code = c("LON.NEW6", "LON.CAP"),
                          Stay.Date = c("30/09/2015", "07/11/2015"),
                          No.of.Rooms = c(3, 1))

#use dcast to go back to wide format
Sample.Bookings.cast <- dcast(Sample.Bookings, Stay.Date ~ Legacy.Hotel.Code, 
                          value.var = "No.of.Rooms")

#Change Stay.Date to Start.Date so we can merge on that column
colnames(Sample.Bookings.cast)[which(colnames(Sample.Bookings.cast) == "Stay.Date")] <- "Start.Date"

#merge on Start.Date
Final.Date <- merge(Sample.Frame, Sample.Bookings.cast, by = "Start.Date", all.x = TRUE)

Final.Date
  Start.Date row.names LON.CAP LON.NEW6
1 07/11/2015         2       1       NA
2 27/10/2015         3      NA       NA
3 30/09/2015         1      NA        3
```

Comment: I have tested this approach on my small and large samples and it appears to work well, thanks very much!  I'll be applying this to a larger set and my next step will be to conduct the same assessment but for the Start.Date +/-1, +/-2, etc.

Comment: How might I adjust the dcast portion of this code so as to produce the same matrix output, however with the MEAN of the "No.of.Rooms" across a specific period, say 30 days (15 days either side of the "Stay.Date")? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get awful close to what you want with dplyr/tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Counts <- group_by(Sample.Bookings, Stay.Date, Legacy.Hotel.Code) %>% 
    summarise(n=n()) %>% 
    spread(Legacy.Hotel.Code, n)
```

You can add the row names from Sample.Frame (which looks like the only info that you need from it with full_join:

```
Sample.Frame$Row.Name<-row.names(Sample.Frame)
full_join(Sample.Frame[,c("Row.Name", "Start.Date")], Counts, by= c("Start.Date"="Stay.Date"))
```

Output:

```
              Row.Name Start.Date LON.CAP LON.CEN2 LON.NEW6
1             E0-001-085571068-9 30/09/2015      NA       NA        2
2             E0-001-086838711-7 07/11/2015      NA       NA        2
3  E0-001-085536178-4@2015102019 20/10/2015      NA       NA        2
4             E0-001-085466318-0 01/07/2016      NA        2       NA
5             E0-001-085591039-5 30/01/2016      NA       NA       NA
6             E0-001-087500856-4 29/04/2016       1       NA       NA
7  E0-001-079398784-2@2015092909 29/09/2015      NA        1       NA
8             E0-001-086021337-5 14/10/2015      NA       NA       NA
9             E0-001-086639435-3 20/12/2015      NA       NA       NA
10            E0-001-087220018-9 27/10/2015      NA       NA       NA
11                          <NA> 01/02/2016       1       NA       NA
12                          <NA> 03/04/2015      NA       NA        1
13                          <NA> 05/02/2016      NA        1       NA
14                          <NA> 05/09/2015      NA       NA        1
15                          <NA> 17/01/2016      NA       NA        1
16                          <NA> 20/02/2016      NA        1       NA
17                          <NA> 22/08/2015      NA       NA        1
18                          <NA> 22/11/2015      NA       NA        1
19                          <NA> 23/07/2015       1       NA       NA
20                          <NA> 28/07/2015      NA       NA        1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When applying to my sample sets, the `Counts` part of the code works well. When I execute the `full_join` elements in the second section of code, I get an output in the console that is similar to your output above, with the following error:

`Warning message:
In outer_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`
(1/2)

Comment: It only appears similar to above in the Console, however it is not changed as a data set in the Environment window; when I select `Sample.Frame` it appears as just the original two columns of the frame.  I would like to able to apply all offered suggestions, so thanks again for your help. (2/2)

Comment: That's a warning about using factors for the join. You could convert to factors before doing the join to make it go away, but that's what it does anyway. To save the output of the join, you need to use an assignment: Sample.Frame <- full_join(...)